# What's the relation between securepaynet and GoDaddy?

Tags: godaddy

I created an account in Google Apps, and during the registration I also created a GoDaddy account (within Google Apps page). And, the username and password Google provided me will only login on [this securepaynet settings page](https://idp.securepaynet.net/login.aspx?SPKey=SPDCC-M1PWDCCWEB03&myaUrl=/default.aspx&prog_id=412956&domain=me.com&user=55555555), not on GoDaddy's official page.

So, what's the relation between securepaynet and GoDaddy? Why can't I login to the GoDaddy page (that have more configurations options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Securepaynet are a seperate hosting company.

Their only link with Godaddy is that their control panel is powered by GoDaddy's software (a control panel, similar to Plesk control panel etc.). As such, you'll be able to log into a securepaynet account, but not a GoDaddy account.

So you can't log into the GoDaddy control panel because you are not a GoDaddy customer.

I hope this helps

Comment: ** This is wrong. Securepaynet is owned by wildwestdomains, and wildwestdomains is the division of godaddy that does reseller accounts. It's all the same company, seperate divions. They are separate, but owned by the same. http://www.godaddy.com/reseller/domain-reseller-api.aspx?ci=44197